# ERB to SLIM с JS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb, slim-lang

Нужно сделать анимацию, с кодом на ERB анимация работает, но если я пробую его записать с SLIM, то анимация пропадает, со слимом начинаю только работать, не пойму где ошибка.

erb:

```
<% if line_item == @current_item %>
  <tr id="current_item">
<% else %>
  <tr>
<% end %>
<td><%= line_item.quantity %>&times;</td>
<td><%= line_item.product.title %></td>
<td class="item_price"><%= number_to_currency(line_item.total_price) %></td>
</tr>
```

slim:

```
- if line_item == @current_item
  tr#current_item

- else
  tr

td
  = line_item.quantity
  | ×
td
  = line_item.product.title
td.item_price
  = number_to_currency(line_item.total_price)
```

Похоже что проблема заключается в файле JS, он не работает со слимом, как его заставить работать со слимо, ума не приложу, сам файл:

js.erb:

```
$('#cart').html("<%= escape_javascript render(@cart) %>");

$('#current_item').css({'background-color':'#88ff88'}).
  animate({'background-color':'#114411'}, 1000);
```

Comment: Нет, проблема не в JS. Посмотрите, какой HTML выходит из вашего Slim'а.

Comment: @D-side спасибо, нашел ошибку, теперь понять, как это записать в SLIM =)

Comment: [Вот так](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15412649/2076787). Можете перевести и собрать плюсики за перевод материала себе :)

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/15412649/2076787

Comment: @D-side Всё равно не могу понять, вроде бы записываю в slim как по мануалу, но ID **current_item** находится на уровень выше, чем нужно.

Comment: Вы же в курсе, что в слиме вложенность считается по отступу слева?

Comment: Да, я в курсе, но я не пойму как условие else записать

Comment: Оно вам тут и не нужно.

Comment: Понял куда копать, благодарю за помощь

Answer (score 0):

```
tr class=('current_item' if line_item == @current_item)
 td
   = line_item.quantity
  | x
 td
   = line_item.product.title
 td.item_price
   = number_to_currency(line_item.total_price)
```